# Listview. Delete all lines except the first 10 lines

Tags: vb.net, listview

Good afternoon.

Can anyone tell me how I delete all the **rows of a Listview**, **leaving** only the **first 10 rows**? And if there are less than 10 lines, then show all the lines that are.

I know how to delete the selected line. Please tell me how to delete all lines in the listview, except for the first 10 lines. Thanks.

```vb
        For Each eachItem As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
            ListView1.Items.Remove(eachItem)
        Next eachItem
```

Comment: What efforts have you made on your own behalf? We're here to help with the stuff you can't do for yourself, not the stuff you can't be bothered to do.

Comment: i only know how to delete the selected row
```vb.net For Each eachItem As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
            ListView1.Items.Remove(eachItem)
        Next eachItem```

Comment: If you loop through the `SelectedItems` collection then obviously you'll only access the selected items. Can you really not think of anything else you could loop over? Are you really not able to write a `For` loop that starts at 10 rather than 0? Put some thought into the logic before you try to write the code and then you might have an idea of what the code actually has to do.

Comment: You can use a `For` loop to count down from some number to another, e.g. `For i = ListView1.Items.Count - 1 To 10 Step -1`, and you can delete a ListViewItem at an index, for example `ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

When using this code, any item with an index higher than 10 will be removed out of the ListView:

```
For Each item In ListView1.Items
   If ListView1.Items.IndexOf(item) > 9 Then
      ListView1.Items.Remove(item)
   End If
Next
```

Comment: That is modifying a collection while enumerating so I would expect would throw an exception. If you want to remove items from a collection then the rule is to use a `For` look rather than a `For Each` loop and to decrease the index rather than increase it. Examples all over the place. If you don't want to remove with an index less than 10 then don't loop past 10. Simple.

Comment: I know that using a for loop would have been shorter and better, but I was trying to keep the original code. I'd rather help others with their original code, than start rewriting everything for them. This is because sometimes the they don't understand the rewritten code as well, as the code they wrote themselves where there are minor modifications. I hope they learn from experience what the best used code is for which situation.